# Showing user Internet disconnected error which can be seen on console

Tags: javascript, firebase, developer-console

Is there a good way to notice the internet disconnected error on console and display this to users on the page? I have this errors on console when I unplug

```
main.js?attr=pltTlu2lwr6ADtz1IRu4oCuycVEk2na6UPNN1MeZWagj4e7pAhHzKoRHw8FmyREe79uc7tRF37s4PLn2kuXMcQ:1025 POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel?database=projects%2Fvuedg3%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&VER=8&RID=94724&CVER=22&X-HTTP-Session-Id=gsessionid&%24httpHeaders=X-Goog-Api-Client%3Agl-js%2F%20fire%2F7.15.0%0D%0A&zx=9kon45lojn55&t=1 net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

Comment: Have you tried to catch an exception from there (with try-catch)? What string does the exception contain?

Comment: Google "progressive web apps offline mode"

Comment: That's not an exception, just an indication in the console, that a network request has failed. Getting information about the network errors programmatically can be done differently in different request methods...

Comment: so there's not another way of getting it than making a request once in a while and see if there's connection?